# Add attributes to wrapped element in Display Suite field template

Tags: display-suite

Is it possible with Display Suite to add an attribute to a field's html tag.

I want to add a class to the read more link. I've tried hook_ds_field_theme_functions_info(), but by that time the link has already been rendered. I was hoping to find a render array.